# While loop until time is reached

Tags: perl

I have an application that loops reading a big text file and runs for at least 48 hours.

I would like to stop its execution from 23.00 to 08.00 (11pm to 8am) and then continue its loop during the day.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't exit from the loop.

#### Edit after Dave Cross' reply

```
my $min = (localtime)[1];
my $hour = (localtime)[2];

while ( $hour > 18 and $min > 0 ) {
    sleep(1);
    $hour = (localtime)[2];
    $min = (localtime)[1];
}
```

This doesn't work as expected. Now it's 18:48 and the loop exits immediately unless I use one hour before:

```
while ( $hour > 17 and $min > 0 )
```

Comment: Also - consider using `alarm`.

Comment: Thank you, edited my code according to Dave' reply.

Comment: `$hour = (localtime)[2]; $min = (localtime)[1];` is a very expensive version of `($hour, $min) = (localtime)[2,1];`

Comment: @LucasRey: Yes, that should be `$hour >= 18`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the time more than once :-)

And rather than calling `strftime()`, why not just use the return value from `localtime()`?

```
my $hour = (localtime)[2];

while ($hour >= 23 or $hour < 8) {
  sleep(1);
  $hour = (localtime)[2];
}
```

**Update:** A more efficient approach might be to work out how long to `sleep()` in order to wake up at 8am. A naive approach would be something like this:

```
if ((localtime)[2]) >= 23) {
  sleep(9 * 60 * 60); # sleep for nine hours
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, this works, but with a side effect. $hour > 23 mean I have to wait midnight. I reported my edited code in the first post, but seems doesn't work as expected

Comment: @DaveCross: That would be `$hour >= 23 or $hour < 8`

Comment: @Borodin: Yeah, I was just about to fix that. Thanks.